# Move element to front without breaking events

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to fix some event code that I'm working on. In this particular case I need to be able to subscribe to a `click` event on an `svg:circle`. However there is also a need to move the circle to the top of the z-index on `mousedown` such that the element can be dragged over the top of other elements.

The way this is done is to take the element out of the DOM and re-insert it in the correct place using a helper function that I'm using from http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/4e0a69d57d3bfc8a82c2 . The problem with doing this is that the event chain seems to have broken taking the element out of the dom preventing the `click` event firing.

I'm wondering if anyone can come up with a better way of doing this which will ensure `click` fires correctly yet still allows changing of the z-index somewhere during the drag lifecycle?

This small example shows how the z-index changes, but the click events don't fire in the console. Clicking on the element again once it's on top does then fire the click correctly.

```js
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    d3.select(this).moveToFront();
  })
  .on("click", function() {
    var fill = d3.select(this).style("fill");
    console.log("You clicked on : " + fill);
  });

d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
```

```css
.red {
  fill: red;
}
.blue {
  fill: blue;
}
.green {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle class="red" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  <circle class="blue" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle class="green" cx="150" cy="150" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Charge to v4 and use `selection.raise()` and `selection.lower()`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If that work's I'd appreciate you adding an answer, although at this point I unfortunately need to find a solution using v3 of D3. Having a look at the code of raise however, it looks like I'd have exactly the same problem - https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/raise.js

Comment: It's complicated to write now because I'm on my mobile, but check this doc I wrote, the fiddle at the end uses "lower" and "raise": http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2537/core-svg-concepts-used-in-d3-js-visualization/18029/svg-the-drawing-order#t=20160912084737911518. Unfortunately, this is v4...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've modified your JSFiddle (I can't use mouseover because I need to support touch) and it has exactly the same problem. https://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/o67wycnt/1/

Comment: Yep, I see that... It's a pity.

Comment: This seems to be browser-related, though, it works fine for me in FF and Chrome but breaks in IE 11.

Comment: @altocumulus that's really interesting to note, due to use only supporting Chrome for our alpha I've not actually checked the other browsers. Although we've been suffering this issue in Chrome

Comment: Use a <use> element at the end of the document to implement dragging. On mousedown hide the circle and point the <use> to the hidden circle then at the end of dragging hide the use and move the circle to the <use> location.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've never used `<use>` but would that not also break the events? Wouldn't the `<use>` need to capture any `mousemove`events etc for dragging, which would then have prevent a mousedown/mouseup on the original circle, therefore causing the browser to not fire a click?

Comment: the <use> wouldn't point to anything and therefore wouldn't be rendered except during the drag. Why not just try it?

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah I might give it a go.

Comment: Can you just change `click` to `mouseup` and check that `mousedown` was the same element?

Comment: @Xotic750 in this case not easily, there's a whole host of events hooked up and it'll get complex sharing events when we sometimes need to supress propagtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered if the problem was with `d3` so I wrote the equivalent in pure JS and had exactly the same result on Chrome as you did with `d3`. I was able to get it to work by replacing `click` with `mouseup` and comparing it with the `mousedown` element, like in my comment. You stated in your comment that this solution was not possible in your case, due to other project restrictions. I thought that I'd post my solution anyway, as it was mentioned that behaviour was different in FF and IE.

```js
const circles = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('circle'));
let mousedown;
for (let circle of circles) {
  circle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    mousedown = e.target;
    e.target.parentNode.appendChild(e.target);
  }, false);
  circle.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    if (mousedown === e.target) {
      console.log('You clicked on : ' + window.getComputedStyle(e.target).fill);
    }
    mousedown = null;
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.red {
  fill: red;
}
.blue {
  fill: blue;
}
.green {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle class="red" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  <circle class="blue" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle class="green" cx="150" cy="150" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Worthwhile adding the answer in case it helps anyone else, so I'll give you an upvote. Have to accept answer as the solution though unless someone has a better D3 answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to come up with a slightly wacky idea, which seems to work, although I'm a little anxious about the performance if there are many elements within the DOM.

The idea is essentially, instead of moving the selection (on `mousedown`) to the top, to move everything else (of the same type, in this case `svg:circle`) behind the element that was mouse-downed upon.

```js
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("mousedown", function() { 
    var that = this;
    d3.select(this.parentNode)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function() { return this !== that; })
      .moveBehind(that);
  })
  .on("click", function() {
    var fill = d3.select(this).style("fill");
    console.log("You clicked on : " + fill);
  });

d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};

d3.selection.prototype.moveBehind = function(element) { 
  return this.each(function() { 
     this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element);   
  });
};
```

```css
.red {
  fill: red;
}
.blue {
  fill: blue;
}
.green {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle class="red" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  <circle class="blue" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle class="green" cx="150" cy="150" r="50" />
</svg>
```